# HTML5 video specs say not to use percentages, but they work?

Tags: html

In the MDN:

> **width**
> The width of the video's display area, in CSS pixels (absolute values only; no percentages).

> **height**
> The height of the video's display area, in CSS pixels (absolute values only; no percentages.)

via: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

But this is working code. (Tested on Chrome/Firefox)
[image: Video width using percentages]

```html
<video controls width="57%">
    <source src="/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm"
            type="video/webm">

    <source src="/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4"
            type="video/mp4">

    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @j08691 - why does the MDN says not to use percentages? But they clearly work.

Comment: The use of `height` and `width` as presentational attributes is deprecated. For that, use CSS. Just like elements such as `<font>` or `<center>`; they may still work (primarily to display older websites that haven't been updated since 1999) but they should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you found a non-standard feature. Probably best to avoid.

Answer (score -1):

Though width in percentage is working to display the video, however, it is not recommended to use it. You should use Pixel instead of %. [HTML Video Attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)